# Isn't possible to store array of strings in defaults write?

Tags: macos, applescript, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I have a use-case where I have to store array of strings in defaults write but it seems like it is not working in applescript.

```
do shell script "defaults write com.subdomain.xyz -array \"abc\" \"abcd\" \"abcde\""
```

**error**

```
error "2022-06-17 13:47:40.780 defaults[5694:216572] Unexpected argument abcd; leaving defaults unchanged." number 1
```

Comment: Works for me, the error about "Meeting workspace" looks like the quoting of the key or values is not correct.

Comment: apologies I have fixed that, it should be abcd. What OS are you on?

Comment: Tested in Monterey and Catalina, but I just noticed that you aren’t declaring a key.  If the key is supposed to be `abc`, then it would be `do shell script "defaults write com.subdomain.xyz \"abc\" -array \"abcd\" \"abcde\""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren’t declaring a key. Here, I added the array name **myNewArray**  as key:

```
do shell script "defaults write com.subdomain.xyz myNewArray -array " & ¬
    "\"abc\" \"abcd\" \"abcde\""
```